# In Rails how to sort records using the results taken by performing some calculations on the associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

It's a bit of a complex situation. I have a `Product` model which have many `order_items`. The two models are like this :

Product :

```
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  code           :string
#  name           :string
...
```

Order items :

```
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  order_id        :integer
#  product_id      :integer
#  color_id        :integer
#  qty             :integer          default("0")
...
```

Order :

```
#  id                  :integer
#  state               :string
#  placed_on           :datetime
...
```

A product can have many order items. An order item can have 1 or many quantities.

In simple terms, what I need to do is, find the top selling products in the current week!

- First we need to get all order items with order state `placed`, `sent` or `delivered` and which are placed on this week
- Then take the sum of the qtys
- Based on those `qtys` rank pick the top 4 order items.

How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: you defenitely need to save the proce at the order_item , if you want to have special promotions prices, etc. look how spree-commerce is doing that.

Comment: @huanson Hi, what did you meant by `proce`

Comment: sry, typo. i mean price

Comment: this is how spree is doing that https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/line_item.rb

Comment: @huanson Ah yes I do save the price in the orderitem... I haven't included those fields in here because I don't think its necessary for this process

Comment: okay, just wanted to bring that to attention. sounds pretty much like shopping and for that, spree commerce is the killer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want join too much, try this

```
class Order < ...
  scope :ordered, ->(where(state: %W(placed, sent, delivered))
  scope :in_this_week, ->(placed_on: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week..Time.zone.now)

order_ids = Order.ordered.in_this_week.pluck(:id)
top_product_ids = OrderItem.where(order_id: order_ids).group(:product_id).sum(:qty).sort_by{|k,v|-v}.first(4).map{|(k,v)| k}
Product.where(id: top_product_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working! Can you please explain the code? The one that's new to me is `top_product_ids = OrderItem.where` line. The rest is ok.

Comment: group(:product_id).sum(:qty) -> get total qty by product_id,
.sort_by{|k,v|-v}.first(4) -> get  4 ids has total qty is top,
.map{|(k,v)| k} -> return product_id

Comment: Yes that's the one... Im new to that part.

Comment: the comment submitted by accident, i just update it :)

Comment: I just checked and you code works perfectly! But one thing... If there are only 3 items which have orders, only 3 will be selected. Is it possible to complete the 4 by adding another product without an order?

Comment: you can do something like this: `top_product_ids = top_product_ids.concat(all_product_ids).first(4)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a raw SQL query to achieve this result in one query, basically your query will be

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select products.name, sum(order_items.qty) as quantity from orders join order_items join products on products.id = order_items.product_id and orders.id = order_items.order_a_id where orders.state in ('placed', 'sent', 'delivered') and orders.placed_on between '#{Time.now-1.week}' and '#{Time.now}' group by products.name order by quantity DESC limit 4").to_a
```

You can tweak the `where` query for the `orders.state in ()` , `orders.placed_at between start_date and end_date` and `limit 4` to match your needs

This will return an array containing the first 4 top selling products in the form of

```
[['product1',100],['product2',90], ...]
```

Where the first element is the product name and the second is total quantity

Answer (score 0):

```
o_ids = Order.where('state in ("placed","sent","delivered") and placed_on >= ? and placed_on <= ?',start_date, end_date).pluck(:id)

sum_of_products = OrderItem.where('order_id in (?)', o_ids).group(:product_id).sum(:qtys)

top_4_products = sum_of_products.sort_by { |k,v| v}.reverse.first(4)
```